# How to avoid loosing precision using implicit conversion (SqlParameter) with DateTime (C#) even if I am using DateTime2 in my SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**This is my definition column in my database.**

[image]

I have a problem with `DateTime` in C# and the value that is being saved into my  database `SQL Server`.

When the applications sends: `2019-06-14 17:10:39.0192950`

Saves into `SQL Server` this: `2019-06-14 17:10:39.0200000`.

And When I need to check if the file already exists in my database using the following function:

```
protected Func<DateTime?, DateTime?, bool> TimeEquals = (x, y) => 
  x.Value.Hour == y.Value.Hour 
     && x.Value.Minute == y.Value.Minute
        && x.Value.Second == y.Value.Second && x.Value.Millisecond == y.Value.Millisecond;
```

That is my code when I insert the values into my `SQL Server` database:

```
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
               command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
                        parameter.Label,
                        parameter.Value
                    ));
            }
```

I start having problems loosing precision. What is the best way to not loose precision when dealing with dates between `C#` and `SQL Server`?

Comment: What type you use to store date in sql?

Comment: Use `DATETIME2` in your tables; `DATETIME` is only accurate to (about) three milliseconds, with weird rounding behavior to boot.

Comment: you need to try changing the SQL parameter type to datetime2 in your c# code, at the moment your parameter is not given a type - it's probably best always to do so

Comment: Are people sure that the alternative question definitely is the answer in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

After establishing the fact that you are using `DateTime2(7)` to store the data in your database, the next hypotheses was naturally that somewhere in your code, the data gets stored in an SQL Server's `DateTime`.

Since [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) puts `DateTime2` in a higher precedence than `DateTime`, it's clear that it's not an implicit conversion inside SQL.

That leaves us with the only option of an implicit conversion to SQL Server's `DateTime` somewhere between the c# code and the SQL Server code - and sure enough, here it is:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
    parameter.Label,
    parameter.Value
));
```

The problem with this code is the same [problem that the `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) method has - since we don't supply the data type, The ADO.Net driver has to guess it - and just like written the article - it guessed wrong.

The correct way to add parameters to a command is using one of the `Add` overloads that takes in both the parameter name and the data type:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = CSDateTimeInstance;
```

Due to the lack of context, I'm not sure how you can incorporate that into your code, but that is the correct solution for this case.

**First version**

In Sql Server, use `DateTime2`.
You are probably using `DateTime` which has the precision of 1/300th of a second, while 
`DateTime2` has the precision of 100ns.

From the [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page:

> Accuracy  Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.

From the [`DateTime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page:

> Precision, scale  0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits.

Comment: Are you *sure*, @FlavioFrancisco, `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2019-06-14 17:10:39.0192950'));` returns value you are saying you have. Perhaps you're using a `datetime` parameter?

Comment: @Larnu If developers would not be nitpicky, who will? thanks, edited that in.

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco Well, if you are using `DateTime2` in your tables, it means that somewhere between the c# and the database table the value is stored in SQL Server's `DateTime` data type. It might be in a stored procedure, it might be an implicit conversion - you will have to check your code to know for sure.

Comment: Technically it could also be stored in a `DATETIME2(2)`, or anything else of lower precision. When a string value is to be implicitly converted to a `DATETIME2`, the engine will pick `DATETIME2(7)` regardless of the destination, so that won't be an issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree, but the image in the post shows `datetime2(7)`, and as you said, implicit conversion would be to the default precision which is 7, so most likely it's an implicit conversion to `DateTime`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: yes, I meant that in addition to `DATETIME`, stored procedures/table types/TVFs/whatever not shown here could be using a `DATETIME2`, just of the wrong precision.

Comment: But then again, according to the [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page, implicit conversion will convert `DateTime` to `DateTime2`, not the other way around. So we are not looking for an SQL Server conversion here. Most likely wrong data type mappings between c# and SQL Server.

Comment: May my problem is when I am using this: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Label, parameter.Value));` and the implicit conversion is converting to DateTime. Thank you everyone!

Comment: I'll bet that's a lesson you won't forget :-) Always specify data types for ado.net parameters! `command.Parameters.Add(parameter.Label, SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = parameter.Value;` is the code you should use.

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco If you could update the question to include the problematic code then I could reopen it and update the answer to include the solution.

Comment: Just to complement the answer I must explicitly convert it to a DateTime instance since I am sending a type object `var dateTimeParameter = new SqlParameter(parameter.Label, SqlDbType.DateTime2)   dateTimeParameter.Value = ((DateTime)parameter.Value); command.Parameters.Add(dateTimeParameter);` The snippet was from a generic method, that is why was generic than I check `if (parameter.Value is DateTime)`. Thanks a lot!